# How to create a list of pre-defined functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I would like to create a list of [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) [pdf's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), having different locations of their maxima, and being multiplied by different factors; then I'd like to calculate those functions' values for different values of `x`.

I have searched on the Internet and tried various things, and I seem to be able to set up the list, but then I fail miserably when it comes to actually using the functions on arguments.

Here's some code:

```
pos     = RandomReal[10,2]
factors = RandomInteger[{1,5},{2}]

gamma1 = 0.5

peaks = Table[factors[[i]]*PDF[CauchyDistribution[pos[[i]],gamma1],x], {i,1,2}]
Print[ peaks ]
Print[ peaks[0.1][[1]] ]
```

This gives me

```
SetDelayed::noval: Symbol peaks in part assignment does not have an immediate value.

SetDelayed::noval: Symbol peaks in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
{3.183098861837907/(1 + 4.*(-6.1318667717670134 + x)^2), 0.6366197723675814/(1 + 4.*(-1.3741656250222944 + x)^2)}
0.1
```

How can I use each element of my array `peaks` like an individual function?

(I'm an absolute Mathematica-beginner, so in advance: sorry for the noob-question...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is best accomplished in two steps. First, you want to construct your list of PDFs as a list of [*pure functions*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), like so:

```
peaks = Table[
  With[{factor = factors[[i]]},
   Composition[factor*# &, 
    PDF@CauchyDistribution[pos[[i]], gamma1]]],
  {i, Length@factors}]
```

Conveniently, `PDF`, when applied to a distribution as its only argument, returns a pure function; I use [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Composition.html) to multiply the result returned by that function by `factor[[i]]`. The `With` statement is there to insert `factors[[i]]` into `Function` despite its non-standard evaluation; you could also use `Evaluate`. Now that you have a list of functions, you can index into them to apply them one at a a time:

```
In[69]:= peaks[[1]][0.1]
Out[69]= 0.376381
```

You can also use [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Through.html) to apply all the functions in a list to a single argument:

```
In[70]:= Through[peaks[0.1]]
Out[70]= {0.376381, 0.0953388}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply!

Comment: Your answer has been extremely useful for the part which followed drawing up the list. Thanks again!

Comment: @canavanin Glad I could help!

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
peaks[x_] := Table[factors[[i]]*PDF[CauchyDistribution[pos[[i]], gamma1], x], {i, 1, 2}]

peaks[0.1]

(* {0.0151052, 0.14023} *)

peaks[0.1][[1]]

(* 0.0151052 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - it works like a charm :)

Comment: @canavanin The answer by Pillsy is the way to go when you become a bit more expert.

Comment: Thought so, but thanks for the pointer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little alternative to Pillsy's and  b.gatessucks's methods. Instead of using `Table[]`, I use `MapThread[]` to loop through the lists of parameters that you want your functions to depend on:

```
n = 4;
pos = RandomReal[10, n];
factors = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {n}];
gamma1 = 0.5;

peaks[t_] = MapThread[(#1 PDF[CauchyDistribution[#2, gamma1], t]) &, {factors, pos}]
```

Now, when you evaluate `peaks[]` at a numeric value, you get a list of length `n`; use `Part[]` to extract components as needed.

```
peaks[1/10]
{0.0113164, 0.318388, 0.00348459, 0.0117505}

peaks[1/10][[3]]
0.00348459
```